# TFS 2013 - Restrict access to collections

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Does anyone know if it's possible to prevent access when there are multiple collections on one server?

I'm doing the setup for two team but it was requested that one team cannot access the other teams collection and vice versa.

All i can seem to find are restrictions on privileges and permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are effectively 3 levels of security in TFS:

1. Server
2. Project Collection
3. Team Project

Users in one Team Project cannot access another Team Project unless they have explicit permissions on it OR they have Collection/Server level permissions.

So, even if a user was a Project Collection Admin on one collection, they would not have access to the other collection unless they were explicitly assigned permissions to it OR had server level permissions.

You can think of a collection as a completely separate TFS instance unless you have server level permissions.

[Permission Reference TFS 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587(v=vs.120).aspx)